# Microsoft Dynamics 365 - Unable to identify a user privilege

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am using Microsoft Dynamics 365 and I am attempting to change the Owner of an Opportunity.  I have System Administrator privileges, but I still get this error message:

```
<Message>Principal user ... is missing prvReadps_application privilege (Id=75b45303-d5b2-494f-9300-04ffa37d2fee)</Message>
```

The prvReadps_application privilege is missing from the [Dynamics documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547441.aspx) so I'm having a hard time tracking down what privilege is missing from my role.  How can I use the privilege name or Id to add the privilege to my role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not you that are missing the privilege - it's the user whom you are trying to give ownership of the Opportunity to. Let's say you have an account owned by User A. If you want to assign this account to user B, user B **MUST** have at least **User-level Read** privilege for the account entity. That is how Dynamics CRM/365 works. The user that you are trying to assign the Opportunity to is probably missing proper the security role.

As other pointed out, ps_application is a custom entity - You should go to your System Customizations area and check its display name (I bet it's something like Application). Now you should check what the security roles of the user are to whom you are trying to change ownership to - you should grant this role Read privilege for this entity (it will be on the last tab of Security Role configuration page).

So, why are you getting this error when assigning Opportunity? I bet that this ps_application entity is related to the Opportunity and the relationship is configured to propagate owner, so by changing owner on Opportunity, you are changing owner of related ps_applications -> and thus you are getting the error, as the user cannot be the owner for such records (does not have read privilege).

Comment: This worked!  We added the lowest level of access (User) to that Security Role, and we were able to assign the Opportunity.  You are correct that it was the user's privilege that needed adjusting and that it was on the last (Custom) tab.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Arun V.'s answer made me realize that I missed the part about you being a System Administrator. Thanks Arun V., and my apologies.

Now I would say that you'll want to focus on the privs of the user to whom are you assigning the record. Their lack of permissions is likely what is preventing the assignment.

As Arun V. pointed out, ps_application could be a custom entity.

Answer (score 2):

`ps_application` is your custom entity. That's why its missing in MS documentation.

`prvReadps_application` - says Read privilege missing, so look for Custom entity tab in Security role.

But System Administrator is a dynamic role, the privilege should be added when a new custom entity is added to the system. Make sure you didn't remove any privileges explicitly.

Also Verify the Security roles of the owner you are trying to assign, for Read privilege of this custom entity.